# Block all internet connections unless connected to OpenVPN server

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, internet

I want to block all internet connections unless I'm connected to my OpenVPN. Now of course, I need to allow connection to the VPN server.

Can this be done, by allowing out/in traffic to/from the VPN server ip, but have a drop all rule afterwards with `iptables`?

I tried to solution proposed by @tachomi, but I don't have internet connection, when the `iptables` rules are set. `iptables-save` states:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Feb  3 00:53:32 2016
*filter
:INPUT DROP [247:40343]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [153:25961]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s <VPN_SERVER_IP>/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s <VPN_SERVER_IP>/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d <VPN_SERVER_IP>/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d <VPN_SERVER_IP>/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  3 00:53:32 2016
```

Answer (score 7):

First Allow your local connection and your `RELATED, ESTABLISHED` connections protocols.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow the internet connection.

Set default chain policies

```
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
$ sudp iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This will deny all kind of inbound/outbound traffic.

Allow your VPN connection

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s [VPN ip connection] -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUPUT -d [VPN ip connection] -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow the VPN connection.

**IF YOU ARE CONNECTED BY SSH YOU MUST ALLOW YOUR IP ADDRESS ALSO AS YOUR LOCALHOST**

UPDATE:

For other connections rules, just allow them.

HTTP for example:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

**PERSONAL RECOMMENDATION**

What I do is to backup my iptables rules with `$ sudo iptables-save > iptables_backup`, then for any change I edit the rules with vim and restore the iptables with `$ sudo iptables-restore < iptables_backup`. This is only a personal practice to avoid duplicating rules.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35261/discussion-on-answer-by-tachomi-block-all-internet-connections-unless-connected).

Comment: How can we allow *all* SSH connections on the local network? And can `[VPN ip connection]` be a hostname?